# Add Image behind NavigationBar and TabBar

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I'm creating  view that contains a ImageView FullScreen, the requirement is that I need to hide and show the navigationBar and tabBar when the user touches the screen but the image needs to stay Full Screen of that device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the top of your view is pinned to the Top Layout Guide. When the nav bar is present, the Top Layout Guide as at the *bottom* of the nav bar. When the nav bar goes away, the Top Layout Guide rises up to the top of the screen, and your view follows along with it.

Instead, pin the top of your view to its superview's top (or top margin). It doesn't move when the nav bar comes and goes.